# Template variables in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code:

```
template <class T>
T GetMax (T a, T b) {
  return (a>b?a:b);
}


int main () {
  int i=51, j=26, k;
  long l=100, m=15, n;
  k=GetMax(i,j);
  n=GetMax(l,m);
  cout << k << endl;
  cout << n << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I change the data type of variables k and n so that they can be dynamic enough to accept the returned value. If the returned value is a double, the k and n will automatically be double, so I need not bother whether I am passing in int or double.

I tried searching it in online and in my books but no luck. Can you Plz help me? I am new to templates.

Comment: Can you try `std::max` instead of `GetMax`?

Comment: I think "GetMax" is more or less the OP's alternate spelling of "foo" here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++11, you can use `auto`:

```
auto k = GetMax(i,j);
auto n = GetMax(l,m);
```

The types of `k` and `n` are deduced from the expression used to initialise them.

Prior to C++11, you would need to give the types explicitly. However, you should always be able to write the types in some form or another, since you know the types of the arguments.

Comment: That is wonderful. I wonder how would auto internally work. Any idea?

Comment: @killerCoder The compiler simply evaluates what the type of the initializer is and makes the variable that type. In this case, that would involve deducing `T` for `GetMax` and seeing that the return type is of type `T`.

Comment: ok.. also, I just wanted to know what all possible datatypes can it cover. I know it will very much overload itself for int, double, long, char, float. But what about char* or arrays?

Say if I have two character arrays and need to find out maximum out of the two, will templates overload the class successfully? If it will, is there any other way for getting the maximum of the two strings other than specializing for character arrays?

Comment: @killerCoder If you pass pointers, the pointer values themselves will be compared. If you want to do string comparison when you get pointers to `char`, you'll want to specialize.

Answer (score 2):

You can't but you don't need to.

GetMax will always be called in the context where you know what types you passed in, so you know what the return type could be.

For example, if you pass in two ints, the result will be int. If you pass in a double and a long, it will be a double.

Think of templates as type safe macros. Replace the call of the function by the body of the function with the types replaced and that's what it will do.

Comment: Thank you. I am very much new to templates so didn't knew this.

Comment: This is true in this case because the `GetMax()` function template takes two arguments of type `T` and returns a value of type `T`. Keep in mind that function templates can also operate on more than one type. For example, also from the C++ Tutorial at cplusplus.com: `T GetMin (T a, U b)`.

Comment: Be careful with the "type-safe macros" view, in particular names whose definitions don't depend on template parameters are bound at template definition, not any particular instantiation done (later and) elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed - I wasn't trying to give a rigorous answer, just a step along the road. It is kind of why they are in the language - to stop folks just using #define.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reference to make compiler warn you if you don't behave.

```
template <class T>
void GetMax (T a, T b, T& output) {
  output = (a>b?a:b);
}
```

But if you can use C++11, use `auto` instead.